# JSON.stringify doesn't work in circulative JSON object. What to do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stringify

e.g.,  in Node.js, if I do this:

```
JSON.stringify(req);
```

Then I will fail because of circulative structure.

is there any setting or way to stringify it easily and skip the circulative part of structure?

Comment: Is it possible to have a circulative structure in JSON? I thought Crockford did a talk where he explicitly said those couldn't be done.

Comment: if you can serialize the object, than you can stringify it. If object can't be serialized than it can't be stringify.

Comment: It is possible.  Default req object in node.js  or any DOM object contains circulative structure. 

how to serialize the object?

Comment: You might be confusing JSON with JavaScript objects. JSON is a subset of JavaScript. Native objects can do things that JSON can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crockford's library (see cycle.js) https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js supports encoding and decoding of circular objects into json (+ jsonpath).